# How to best implement a gRPC app that efficiently publishes messages to Kafka?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, grpc

I have a gRPC application which takes in requests, publishes a message to a Kafka cluster, and then returns a response back to the client indicating whether or not the publish request succeeded. Right now I have something along the lines of:

```
    var result = await _KafkaClient.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, kafkaMessage, cancellationToken);
    return new Response {
        Success = result.PersistenceStatus == result.Persisted
    };
```

However, it's important that I minimize the amount of time that this publish call takes and want to understand potential optimizations I can make. I have found some articles indicating that the .NET `Produce` function is actually significantly faster than the `ProduceAsync` function (https://concurrentflows.com/kafka-producer-sync-vs-async) but I'm unsure how I can switch to `Produce` in my flow given that I need to wait for the the call to actually complete so I can return a response status back to the client, rather than just "firing and forgetting". For example, if I did something like this:

```
    var published = false;
    _KafkaClient.Produce(kafkaTopic, kafkaMessage, (deliveryReport) =>
    {
        if (deliveryReport.Status == PersistenceStatus.Persisted)
        {
            published = true;
        }
    });
    return new Response {
        Success = published
    };
```

then I would just return false since the delivery report is handled on a separate thread, right? Is there any way for me to wait for the response to the publish call while still using the `Produce` function? Alternatively, are there any other optimizations anybody would suggest?

Comment: Using `await` is the only way for this to work

Answer (score 0):

> I have a gRPC application that takes in requests, publishes a message to a Kafka cluster, and then returns a response back to the client indicating whether or not the publish request succeeded.

There are other tools for getting messages onto Kafka using gRPC service definitions. One is the open-source project [Zilla](https://github.com/aklivity/zilla), which is already optimized for latency and scale. It lets you expose your [gRPC service and delivers the request and response messages onto Kafka](https://docs.aklivity.io/zilla/latest/tutorials/grpc/grpc-intro.html).

Comment: Wouldn't adding external systems only add latency? As question says - _important that I minimize the amount of time that this publish call takes_

Comment: In this case, Zilla would be in place of the code being written so the number of systems in between the caller and Kafka would be the same.

Comment: But if I had a custom gRPC server that was forwarding traffic to Kafka, then I control the logic of that, and cannot be directly replaced with Zilla

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to apply custom logic, you would need to write code. This question centered around a separate client only needing to get a message onto Kafka. In that case, Zilla can do that and more. Then, any business logic can be written and applied downstream from that entry point. 

In Zilla, you supply your `.proto` file, and it exposes that service. Meaning it can be a drop-in replacement for any ingress code. Much the same way nginx or envoy logic can be implemented by the controller layer, but many cases benefit from using them instead.